# Issue Pulling a specific revision from SVN using SharpSVN

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

If I use tortoiseSVN, I can navigate to the following URI and see that the file is indeed there:

svn://server/DocRoot/WordFile.doc

and I can see that the current revision of the doc is 6.

However, this code does not work, and I’m at a loss as to what I’m doing wrong:

```
using (SvnClient svn = new SvnClient ())
{
   Uri repos = new Uri (svnPath); // svnPath = "svn://server/DocRoot/WordFile.doc"
   SvnUriTarget target = new SvnUriTarget (repos, revision);
   MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream ();
   svn.Write (target, buffer);
   return buffer.ToArray ();
}
```

This block throws an exception, saying that it couldn’t find “svn://server/DocRoot/WordFile.doc@6”, yet tortoise can find it. Any ideas as to where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code above works fine, the issue was that SVNPaths in subversion are CASE SENSITIVE.